# Lines endings confusion

Tags: newline, plaintext, line-endings

How are line endings in plain text files stored in the document and what possibilities exist? I read that line endings in UNIX-based systems are LF  and hence represented by `\n` yet I would not know how to display these characters.

Writing a simple file in VS Code on Ubuntu with the LF option, bash gives me the following output for my file:

```
$ cat -e file.txt
a$
b$
```

When changed to CRLF in VS Code I get:

```
cat -e file.txt
a^M$
b^M$
```

And strangely, in some files I've been working on I get endings like `^K` or `^H`

whatever that even means. If you can help with my confusion or have some good source of information about the issue, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Explanation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it

Comment: Thank you, but what about ^H and ^K?

Comment: They represent the backspace & vertical tab characters respectively - these are control characters so have no exact visual representation so ^X is substituted for display so you can see them. You would not expect to see them in a plain text file, they are nothing to do with line endings.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you. Are those representations universal for all systems? And can I somehow display the bytecode of only the line endings, or would that need a more complicated script?